# Real time display of result of user input in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to display result of two user inputs-Number field but in vain. It should happen in real time, ie without any need to press any button, result should be displayed as field data changes with default value of it be 'Zero'. 
Here number1 and number2 are two inputs and grosstotal is result of number1+number2.
Please help.

***Update :***
I have put in code as suggested [by @Jacky] but app is crashing as soon as i try to input any number. Tried using debug [from the point I am doing input of data on emulator] and have put in its result too for it may be of any help.
Kindly help.

**MainActivity :**

```
package com.ck.cg;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText getnumber1;
private EditText getnumber2;
private TextView displaygrossTotal;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getnumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    getnumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
    displaygrossTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grossTotal);

    getQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            GetSum();
        }
    });

    getRate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            GetSum();
        }
    });
}


private void GetSum() {
    int a = 0, b = 0, total;

    if (getnumber1.getText() != null && !getnumber1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(getnumber1.getText().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            a = 0;
        }
    }

    if (getnumber2.getText() != null && !getnumber2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        try {
            b = Integer.parseInt(getnumber2.getText().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            b = 0;
        }
    }
    total = a + b;
    displaygrossTotal.setText(total);
}
}
```

**xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ck.cg.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:labelFor="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/number_1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number2"
    android:labelFor="@+id/number2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/number_2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grossTotal"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gross_total"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Debug :**

```
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.ck.cg, PID: 6801
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4555)
                  at com.ck.cg.MainActivity.GetSum(MainActivity.java:77)
                  at com.ck.cg.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:10)
                  at com.ck.cg.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:37)
                  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8203)
                  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10382)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1218)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:579)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:509)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
                  at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
                  at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6285)
                  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:6075)
                  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2688)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9960)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:405)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1798)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3021)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:319)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6246)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6181)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Before your question gets down voted to the ground, take a look at the TextWatcher Listener in android, you get a callback on beforeTextChanged, afterTextChanged and textChanged, 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: i removed old answer after review it ~~, so sorry for any trouble

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous post, as it cause you alot trouble. After review, I am not sure why do I give you the answer with `TextWatcher`, causing alot of trouble to you, too. Here is the MainActivity, with simple `OnClickListener`:

```
    private EditText getnumber1;
    private EditText getnumber2;
    private TextView displaygrossTotal;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getnumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
        getnumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
        displaygrossTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grossTotal);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a = 0, b = 0, total;
                if (getnumber1.getText() != null && !getnumber1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    try {
                        a = Integer.parseInt(getnumber1.getText().toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        a = 0;
                    }
                }

                if (getnumber2.getText() != null && !getnumber2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    try {
                        b = Integer.parseInt(getnumber2.getText().toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        b = 0;
                    }
                }
                total = a + b;
                displaygrossTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thnks for ur effort buddy.... but I dont want button to be pressed for calculation.... It has to be instant while we tap in numbers...!!!

Comment: moreover numbers are decimals (Double/float) so integer wont work I suppose.